# what is default throttle value for Excel 2010

Tags: excel, throttling, rtd

I see from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140060(v=office.10).aspx
that data throttle value for Excel 2002 is 2 seconds.  but I can't find the default value for Excel 2003, 2007 & 2010. I assume they are 2 seconds, too. But just want to know for sure. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value two ways, either via the registry:
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Options\RTDThrottleInterval`

[replace the 14.0 with your office version]

..or via the Immediate window in Excel's VBA editor:

```
? Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval
```

I get 2000ms in Office 2010.

Comment: Thanks. in my registry, I did not see the key RTDThrottleInterval at all.  I just checked with the second way, I get 2000ms in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The default for Excel 2010 and 2013 is `2000 milliseconds`. See the below links to MSDN:

[Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837824%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Office 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837824%28v=office.15%29.aspx)